# Keeping track of scene collectables

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, box2d, andengine

On this particular level, I have some objects which I made with `Tiled map editor`, these objects are on an object layer of the mapt and should be collected only once. My question is how do I allow the player to collect and keep track of which of the objects have been previously collected. I am not sure as to how I would keep track of these items on the scene to figure out which ones are already gone, and which ones are left. Currently all these collectables have the same tag `coin`, thanks for any help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find something for that here: [Collidable Tiles With TMXTiledMap](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/collidable-tiles-with-tmxtiledmap-t566.html).

> In this example I am implementing a "collectable" tile. These
>   collectables can be anything from powerups, food, points, etc... You
>   can see that on the collected event I set the tile texture to null.
>   This removes the tile from the map. As long as the tile you are
>   removing is from the foreground then the background tile should show
>   up underneath.

The code was written for GLES1 (it's CIRCA 2010), so it won't translate exactly (or more precisely, I don't *know* it will).  This should get you started in the right direction.